# jquery .css('text-decoration') doesn't work from parents

Tags: jquery, css, text-decorations

I have to get needed css property of element (properties may be inherited from it's parent)

Standart jquery .css() can do it.

So i have such an HTML:

```
<div id="container"> some text<br>
        <span id="some">Our element</span>
   <br> some text
</div>

<div id="result">
</div>
```

css:

```
#some {
    font-weight:bold;
}

#container {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: rgb(0,255,0);
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

and jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    var decor = $("#some").css('text-decoration');
    var weight = $("#some").css('font-weight');
    var color = $("#some").css('color');
    var size = $("#some").css('font-size');
    var result = "<br><b>our object's own property:</b>"
    result += "<br>font-weight:" + weight + "<br>";
    result += "<br><b>inherited properties:</b><br>";
    result += "color: " + color + "<br>font-size: " + size + "<br>text-decoration: " + decor;

    $("#result").html(result);
});
```

All properties are displayed but text-decoration - not. But why?
http://jsfiddle.net/aQYs2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

text-decoration is defined with **Inherited:no** inside the css-specification, but the other properties you use inside your example are defined with **Inherited:yes**

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#propdef-text-decoration

So everything works really fine :)

Comment: Don't you know alternative of text-decoration: underline. What other css properties can make underline without text-decoration? Because I need inheritance =)

Comment: No, but `#container *{text-decoration:inherit;}` should do it.